# Is there an integer i where i<2 && i>10?

Tags: c#, numbers, integer, int, integer-overflow

```
if(i<2 && i>10){
    //code here will never be reached or what?
}
```

Just in case of an integer overflow maybe?

Comment: that code will never be reached as a number cant be less than 2 and greater than 10

Comment: What is the *real* problem that lead to this question? Why do you wonder about something that logically can't happen? Is there a bug in some existing code that makes it seems like the condition could be true? Perhaps you should ask about that instead then. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: i tried to understand the code of an earlier developer, and changing it without trying to understand it could destroy some logic in it. I found out that this was just a mistake and the aim was to check if i is in the range of 2 and 10 so it was meant to be if(2<=i && i<=10). Furthermore, I still wonder if that can happen. Will try to produce some cases

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: it's c#  @PaulFloyd

Comment: OK, my answer below is still valid

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I wrote this not knowing c# is the language used. I've used C++ but I believe that the principle is also valid for c#.

- there is no single integer that satisfies the condition
- the compiler may well optimize away the body of the if condition (see here for an [example on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Yj7tji))
- however, in the case of `i` being `volatile` it is possible that the value of `i` changes between the `i<2` and the `i>10` tests. In this case the if body can be reached.

However, though it may be theoretically possible it is highly unlikely that this was the intention.

Here's my example code

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

void foo(int i)
{
    if (i < 2 && i > 10)
    {
        cout << "The impossible happened in foo\n";
    }
}

void bar(volatile int i)
{
     if (i < 2 && i > 10)
    {
        cout << "The impossible happened in bar\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, it is indeed possible that this happens in C# when multithreading, but never if `i` is a parameter to the method (it could happen if `i` is a property of the class it's contained in, for example)

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible for some c# (assuming c# because it's tagged... not assuming integer even if it's tagged because the right-hand comparison is still an integer, so it matches the tags! ;-) ) code to go into that `if`... take:

```
public class Foo {
   public static bool operator> (Foo a, int b) {
       return true;
   }
   public static bool operator< (Foo a, int b) {
       return true;
   }
}
```

Then:

```
Foo i = new Foo();
if(i<2 && i>10){
  Console.WriteLine("Pass!");
}
```

Guess the output? [Check it out here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KK68Ek)

Another way, with no extra classes or operator overloading:

```
private static bool odd;
public static int i { get { odd = !odd; return odd ? 1 : 11; } }
```

[Check it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mbS7Sj)

Otherwise, it could also happen if multithreading (if the value of `i` changes bewtween the comparisons) unless you apply correct locking

Comment: ok so when overloading the operator, it would work with that ,manipulation' :)

Comment: yeah, and I just added one more way it could pass without extra classes or overloading... and there's also the multithreading possibility... there are multiple weird ways in which that could happen